# Can send and receive mail with Evolution, but can't save drafts or view sent mail

Tags: 16.04, email, evolution, ms-exchange

I am using Evolution 3.18.5.2 with Ubuntu 16.04. My work uses Office 365 for mail, which I have linked with Evolution via IMAP. This suffices to send and receive mail. But for some reason I am unable to save drafts or view sent mail. No error message pops up when I try to save an Email, but the draft does not appear in my drafts folder; likewise, when I send an Email it does not show up in my Outbox or Sent Items folders (I'm not sure why I have both). How can I get these features to work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Outbox - is out going mail that has not yet been sent to the outgoing server.
Sent   - is for copies of mail that has been sent by the server. This recording of sent mail can be disabled.

Are you looking in the right folders?
Most e-mail clients have two sets of folders. One set is a clone of the server folders. The other set is local mail folders.
Work done in the client is saved to the local folders (drafts, outbox and sent).
Depending on your server setting, sent e-mail may be recorded in your server's sent folder.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up the distinction between Outbox and Sent Items. When when I send an Email, it does not appear in either of these folders, and if I try to save an Email as draft, it does not appear in my Drafts folder. I'm not sure what could be going wrong if these are just local folders. Does Evolution have a setting to determine my local mail folders?

Comment: I have not used Evolution, I use Thunderbird, but typically the client creates the local folders itself. and they are listed under the server folders